# Pass by Reference program c++

Tags: c++

I've only been coding for a few months and I've come across a roadblock for one of my assignments. The description is

> "Rewrite the purse porgram given with functions to perform insert and
>   remove operations. The function initialize (int& p, int& n, int& d,
>   int& q) will initialize pennies, nickels, dimes and quarters to zeros.
>   The function insert (int& p, int& n, int& d, int& q) will add pennies,
>   nickels, dimes and quarters. The function dollars() will return the
>   dollars. The function remove (int& p, int& n, int& d, int& q) will
>   subtract pennies, nickels, dimes and quarters. The function display()
>   returns a new String to print the content of the purse with remaining
>   pennies, nickels, dimes and quarters."

This is what I've been able to come up with so far.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters, p, n, d, q;
   float total;

   void initialize(int&, int&, int&, int&);
   void insert(int&, int&, int&, int&);
   void remove(int&, int&, int&, int&);
   float dollars(int, int, int, int);
   void print(int, int, int, int, float);


   initialize(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters);
   total = dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters);
   print(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters, total);

   insert(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters);
   total = dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters);
   print(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters, total);

   remove(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters);
   total = dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters);
   print(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters, total);

}
void initialize(int& pennies, int& nickels, int& dimes, int& quarters)

{
    pennies=0;
    nickels=0;
    dimes=0;
    quarters=0;
}

void insert(int& pennies, int& nickels, int& dimes, int& quarters)
{
    int p, n, d, q;
    cout << "Insert pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters:";
    cin >> p, n, d, q;

    pennies +=p;
    nickels +=n;
    dimes +=d;
    quarters +=q;

}

void remove(int& pennies, int& nickels, int& dimes, int& quarters)
{
    int p, n, d, q;
    cout << "Remove pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters:";
    cin >> p, n, d, q;

    pennies -=p;
    nickels -=n;
    dimes -=d;
    quarters -=q;

}

float dollars(int pennies, int nickels, int dimes, int quarters, float total)
{
    total= pennies + 5*nickels + 10*dimes + 25*quarters;
    total=(float)total/100;

    return total;
}
void print(int pennies, int nickels, int dimes, int quarters, float total)
{
    cout << quarters << "quarters+ " << dimes << " dimes+" << nickels << " nickels+" << pennies << " pennies= $" << total <<"\n";

}
```

I've been using onlinegdb.com to compile all my programs as that's all my class requires me to use. When I compile this program, I get

```
/tmp/ccd19JQt.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2b): undefined reference to `dollars(int, int, int, int)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x6a): undefined reference to `dollars(int, int, int, int)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa9): undefined reference to `dollars(int, int, int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to get this program to compile and run? Thank you so much.

This is how I changed it to get it to work. Thanks for the advice.

```
int main()
{
   int pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters, p, n, d, q;
   float total;

   void initialize(int&, int&, int&, int&);
   void insert(int&, int&, int&, int&);
   void remove(int&, int&, int&, int&);
   float dollars(int, int, int, int);
   void print(int, int, int, int, float);


   initialize(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters);
   total = dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters);
   print(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters, total);

   insert(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters);
   total = dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters);
   print(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters, total);

   remove(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters);
   total = dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters);
   print(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters, total);

}
void initialize(int& pennies, int& nickels, int& dimes, int& quarters)

{
    pennies=0;
    nickels=0;
    dimes=0;
    quarters=0;
}

void insert(int& pennies, int& nickels, int& dimes, int& quarters)
{
    int p, n, d, q;
    cout << "Insert pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters:";
    cin >> p>>n>>d>>q;

    pennies +=p;
    nickels +=n;
    dimes +=d;
    quarters +=q;

}

void remove(int& pennies, int& nickels, int& dimes, int& quarters)
{
    int p, n, d, q;
    cout << "Remove pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters:";
    cin >> p>>n>>d>>q;

    pennies -=p;
    nickels -=n;
    dimes -=d;
    quarters -=q;

}

float dollars(int pennies, int nickels, int dimes, int quarters)
{
    float total;
    total= pennies + 5*nickels + 10*dimes + 25*quarters;
    total=(float)total/100;

    return total;
}
void print(int pennies, int nickels, int dimes, int quarters, float total)
{
    cout << quarters << "quarters+ " << dimes << " dimes+" << nickels << " nickels+" << pennies << " pennies= $" << total <<"\n";

}
```

Comment: your method declarations are inside of main. move them out.

Comment: Why did you add `float total` to the parameter list of `dollars`? It should be a local variable by how you use it. Not a parameter.

Comment: @DanielA.White - That's legal, albeit quirky.

Comment: Any function that takes all its parameters as non-const references is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: The declaration of `dollars()` in `main()` accepts 4 arguments.   The definition of `dollars()` has 5 arguments.    They don't match.   Make them match.     It is not necessary to move the declarations outside `main()`, but is advisable (e.g. if you ever want your functions to call each other).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the declaration:

```
float dollars(int, int, int, int);
//            1    2    3    4
```

You've declared 4 arguments.

Here is the function call:

```
total = dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters);
//              1        2        3      4
```

You pass 4 arguments. So far so good.

Here is the definition:

```
float dollars(int pennies, int nickels, int dimes, int quarters, float total)
//            1            2            3          4             5
{ ...
```

You've given a definition for a 5 argument function `dollars(int,int,int,int,float)`. The linker error is because of lack of definition for `dollars(int,int,int,int)` which you call, but didn't define.

Solution: define the function `dollars(int,int,int,int)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to get the program working with your help.